MBPro 2014 big latency, packet loss, ping spikes on Big Sur
One of a sudden encounter with laggy internet, as follows:

ping of 1.1.1.1 rised from 12 to 120, with connection speed go down
some packet loss, and
ping spikes from time to time.

To check if it is a hardware issue i booted from live cd and under linux (parrot OS) all works flawlessly - ping is 12 ms as was before on macos.
What i try to do:

reboot router and mac
reset nvram
delete wifi connection from system preferences
delete setting files from - /Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/
disable AWDL
disable roaming (not sure it actually disable AWDL)
disable bluetooth

next step i think to perform is OS re-installation, any help appreciated

problem was in WARP app by cloudflare, due to some bug it was not shown any where but it proxies connection so delay was caused by it. So after disabling the WARP all is fine. Regards
